# How can I format this in lyx?

Tags: spacing, lyx, arrays

I'm trying to format a confusion matrix in lyx. I want the data to look like this.

```
    a    b    c    d    e    f    g   <-- classified as
    1    5   10    8    4    2    0 |    a = 3
    3   39  100   66    6    2    0 |    b = 4
    4   74 1385  596   69   10    0 |    c = 5
   10   47  631 1763  346   39    0 |    d = 6
    1   11   80  417  533   37    0 |    e = 7
    1    0   11   50   62   69    0 |    f = 8
    0    0    0    1    4    0    0 |    g = 9
```

Notice how it is structured properly in the sense that all values align to a column and row.

When I paste this in lyx it looks like below and I don't seem to have a way to add spaces or tabs.

[image]

I'm using the default Article class.

Answer (score 3):

LyX can handle direct copy-paste of ASCII tables into lyx tables. You just have the columns delimited by tabs in the ASCII table. Then copy the ASCII table from your ASCII editor to the clipboard. In LyX, create an empty table with the appropriate number of columns and rows, e.g. by the menu Insert->Table or even quicker with the pulldown menu in the toolbar. Then place the cursor in the upper left cell of this empty table and do Ctrl-Shift-V. This is much faster than retyping the table as  LaTeX markup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to input it in LyX, but this LaTeX code should do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{7}{r} | c@{}l }
\multicolumn{1}{c}{a} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{b} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{c} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{d} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{e} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{f} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{g} &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$\leftarrow$ classified as} \\[\jot]
    1 &   5 &  10 &   8 &   4 &   2 &   0 & a & ${}=3$ \\
    3 &  39 & 100 &  66 &   6 &   2 &   0 & b & ${}=4$ \\
    4 &  74 &1385 & 596 &  69 &  10 &   0 & c & ${}=5$ \\
   10 &  47 & 631 &1763 & 346 &  39 &   0 & d & ${}=6$ \\
    1 &  11 &  80 & 417 & 533 &  37 &   0 & e & ${}=7$ \\
    1 &   0 &  11 &  50 &  62 &  69 &   0 & f & ${}=8$ \\
    0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   4 &   0 &   0 & g & ${}=9$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want all columns with equal width, then `siunitx` seems to provide the easiest way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{7}{S[table-format=4.0]} | c@{}l }
\multicolumn{1}{c}{a} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{b} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{c} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{d} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{e} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{f} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{g} &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$\leftarrow$ classified as} \\[\jot]
    1 &   5 &  10 &   8 &   4 &   2 &   0 & a & ${}=3$ \\
    3 &  39 & 100 &  66 &   6 &   2 &   0 & b & ${}=4$ \\
    4 &  74 &1385 & 596 &  69 &  10 &   0 & c & ${}=5$ \\
   10 &  47 & 631 &1763 & 346 &  39 &   0 & d & ${}=6$ \\
    1 &  11 &  80 & 417 & 533 &  37 &   0 & e & ${}=7$ \\
    1 &   0 &  11 &  50 &  62 &  69 &   0 & f & ${}=8$ \\
    0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   4 &   0 &   0 & g & ${}=9$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what are those little "ghost" lines running across row "e"?  i'd suspect my eyes or my monitor, except that they (the lines, not the eyes) persist when i scroll up to enlarge the image, and it's consistent on both examples.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Artifacts when getting the image as a screen shot. I polished them.

Comment: You could past the above latex code, or simply construct the table directly in LyX.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the answers are all Latex ways of doing it. The Lyx way of doing it is to click on Insert | Table, and drag your cursor in the resulting dialog box until you have an 8x8 table.  Fill your data into the table cells.  They will expand as you enter data.  You can then select the last column, choose Options, click on the borders tab, and edit it until only the left border is selected.  You also might want to do likewise in the penultimate column, for the right border.

Typically, the next step is to select your table (not just cells within it).  I click to the left, hold down shift, and hit right arrow.  Then choose Insert | Float | Table.
This buys you a handy caption, and some options on where to place the table when you edit the float's options.

(Multi-page tables are a little more complex, and only needed if you need a table to span pages.)